# correct use of Meteor.userId()

Tags: meteor

This Meteor server code tries to use Meteor.userId() in public method "sendEmail", but sometimes I get the error

> Error Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId

```
lib = (function () {

  return Object.freeze({
    'sendEmail': function(msg){
      let userId = Meteor.userId(); 
      //do stuff for this user
    },
    'otherPublicMethod': function(){
      //do other things then use sendEmail
      lib.sendEmail();  // <---- Error Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId
    }
  });
}());

// Now I call sendEmail from any where, or can I?

Meteor.methods({
  'sendEmail': (msg) => {
    lib.sendEmail(msg); // <---- NO error when this is called
  },
});
```

How can it be fixed? thx

Comment: `userId()` is not permitted to be used within `Publications`, but there is no restriction to use it within `Methods`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm going to gently suggest you replace your use of [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). instead, you can take advantage of [ES16 modules](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/modules.html) to define your common functions.

as you've indicated, Meteor.userId() is available in method calls, but won't be available in standalone functions on the server. the pattern i use, when invoking such functions from a method call, is to pass in the userId (or actual user). e.g.

imports/api/email/server/utils/emailUtils.js:

```
const SendEmail = function(userId, msg) {
    // do stuff
};

export {SendEmail};
```

imports/api/email/server/emailMethods.js:

```
import {SendEmail} from '/imports/api/email/server/utils/emailUtils';

Meteor.methods({
    'sendEmail': (msg) => {
        check(msg, String);
        // other security checks, like user authorization for sending email
        SendEmail(Meteor.userId(), msg);
    },
});
```

now, you have a re-usable SendEmail function you can call from any method or publish. additionally, by following this pattern, you're one step closer to creating testable code. i.e. it's easier to test a function into which you're injecting a userId than it is to mock "this.userId" or "Meteor.userId()".

Comment: One reason I like the IIFE over modules is that I can call the public method like funcName.methName and know which one I am calling, i.e. less comments to write.

Answer (score 1):

If lib.sendEmail is being called from any async method, then ensure that you bind Meteor environment 
e.g. check code below which simulates the async behaviour

```
lib = (function () {
    return Object.freeze({
        'sendEmail': function (msg) {
            let userId = Meteor.userId();
            console.log(userId);
            //do stuff for this user
        },
        'otherPublicMethod': function () {
            //do other things then use sendEmail
            lib.sendEmail();  // <---- Error Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId
        }
    });
}());

// Now I call sendEmail from any where, or can I?

Meteor.methods({
    'sendEmail': (msg) => {
        //simulate async behaviour + bind environment
        Meteor.setTimeout(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
            lib.sendEmail(msg); // <---- NO error when this is called
        }));
        //output :
        // null - if user has not logged in else
        // actual userId - if user is loggedin

        //simulate async behaviour without binding environment
        Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
            lib.sendEmail(msg); // <---- error when this is called
        });
        //output :
        // Exception in setTimeout callback: Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.
    },
});
```